# Help in solving a congruence equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So I need to write down the smallest natural number $x$ that satisfies this statement:

$11x$ has reminder of $1$, when divided by $2,3,5,7$.

So I know it's somehow  solved by using modular arithmetic but I wonder how can I apply it here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks as if $11x$ has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $210$

Comment: Essentially you need to solve $11x+210y=1$ in integers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: Now note that $210=11 \times 19 +1$ and so $11\times (210-19) = 11^2 \times 19 +11-11 \times 19 +1$